# TableViewer: how to force a selection change

Tags: java, swt, selection, jface

When invoking `tableViewer.getTable().selectAll()` the registered selection listeners will not be notified (as usual for all kind of programmatic selection changes in SWT - according to my knowledge). How can I trigger an internal selection change to the `TableViewer` so it notifies all listeners?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
yourTableViewer.getTable().notifyListeners( SWT.Selection, null );
```

Where `null` is an `Event`.  Remember that this is the `Event` received by your listener.

Comment: In the context of the TableViewer, this is OK, but if there are other `SWT.Selection` listeners on the table, these might get a little confused as the supplied `Event` is not filled out completely...

Comment: Good point.  This is the kind of thing that needs good documenting.